# Handling Password Rotation with C3P0

Tags: java, passwords, c3p0

We are using C3P0 to manage our connection pools for some java applications (some using JBoss, some using Hibernate).  The issue is that the database admins want to be able to rotate passwords on the databases.

The passwords are stored in an external vault, so if the password on a database is changed, the vault is updated at the same time.  Our application could respond to a password change by closing down the existing ComboPooledDataSources, fetching the new password, and creating a new ComboPooledDataSource.  But it can only do so if it knows the password has changed.

Unfortunately, it seems that when C3P0 encounters an exception when attempting to create a connection, it simply logs the exception and discards it.  Thus, a password change would result in a failed connection-creation, a log message, and then eventually a retry.  Before we would have any way of noticing the error, the account would already be locked.

The solution I am imagining would be an exception callback: when C3P0 attempts to create a connection and fails, rather than simply logging and discarding the exception, it would have the option for us to specify a callback to handle the exception.  Then we could write code that would identify the incorrect-password exception and respond by closing the ComboPooledDataSource, and having the application fetch the new password and create a new one.

Is this possible?  Is anything similar possible?